# Class has no initializers static let dataService (swift)

Tags: swift

dataservice.swift

class DataService    --> class data service has no initializers
static let dataService = DataService()   --> data service cannot be 
constructed because it has no accessible initializers

```
class DataService {

static let dataService = DataService()

private var _BASE_REF = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
var fileUrl: String


var BASE_REF: FIRDatabaseReference {
    return _BASE_REF
}

var storageRef : FIRStorageReference {
    return FIRStorage.storage().reference()
    }


func SignUp(username: String, email: String, password: String, data: NSData) {

    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        let changeRequest = user?.profileChangeRequest()
        changeRequest?.displayName = username
        changeRequest?.commitChangesWithCompletion({ (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

        })

        let filePath = "profileImage/\(user!.uid)"
        let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        self.storageRef.child(filePath).putData(data, metadata: metadata, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error.description)")
                return
            }

            self.fileUrl = (metadata?.downloadURLs! [0].absoluteString)!
            let changeRequestPhoto = user!.profileChangeRequest()
            changeRequestPhoto.photoURL = NSURL(string: self.fileUrl)
            changeRequestPhoto.commitChangesWithCompletion({ (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }else{
                    print("profile updated")

                }

            })
            let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.login()



        })
    })


}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your fileUrl: String either needs a default value or needs to be set in an initializer.

just set its value as a blank string "" and fill it in later when you need to.

```
var fileUrl: String = ""
```

The proper way is to give it a value in an initializer, but you might not know the value at the time of instantiation. So just give it a blank value for now. A class uses initializers to guarantee all properties have a value and the class is totally ready for use upon its creation. If your properties all have default values, or are optional, then initializers are not needed.

Comment: thanks! , it solved the problem, but now there's a new one                                                                                                                                                                  global "var" declaration requires an initializer expression or getter/setter specifier                                                                                                            var storageRef : FIRStorageReference {
return FIRStorage.storage().reference()
}       ----> (error is here)

Comment: @Drean im not sure about that one

Answer (score 0):

import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseStorage

class DataService {

static let dataService = DataService()

private var _BASE_REF = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
var fileUrl: String

```
var BASE_REF: FIRDatabaseReference {
    return _BASE_REF
    }

var storageRef : FIRStorageReference {
    return FIRStorage.storage().reference()

}


func SignUp(username: String, email: String, password: String, data: NSData) {

    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        let changeRequest = user?.profileChangeRequest()
        changeRequest?.displayName = username
        changeRequest?.commitChangesWithCompletion({ (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

        })

        let filePath = "profileImage/\(user!.uid)"
        let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        self.storageRef.child(filePath).putData(data, metadata: metadata, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if let error = error {
        print("\(error.description)")
                return
            }

            self.fileUrl = (metadata?.downloadURLs! [0].absoluteString)!
            let changeRequestPhoto = user!.profileChangeRequest()
            changeRequestPhoto.photoURL = NSURL(string: self.fileUrl)
            changeRequestPhoto.commitChangesWithCompletion({ (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }else{
                    print("profile updated")

                }

            })
            let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.login()



        })
    })


}
```

}